why is my svm taking much time to run what changes should i make in my code?
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

reg_svr = SVR(kernel='rbf')
reg_svr.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

test['prediction_svr'] = reg_svr.predict(X_test_scaled)

score_svr = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(test['PJME_MW'], test['prediction_svr']))
print(f'RMSE Score on Test set (SVR): {score_svr:0.2f}')


If you offer a reprex, that will make it easier to obtain a useful answer.

It is difficult to answer the question based on the information that you provide. E.g., it would be important to know what kind of dataset you are considering (how many features, how many data records). Also "taking much time" is not clear (is it minutes or hours, are you comparing to another method, or is it in comparison to a benchmark test?). Providing all these information will make a useful answer much more likely.

There are several possibilities to speed up your SVM training. Follow the steps mentioned in the answer

SVC classifier taking too much time for training

and

SVM using scikit learn runs endlessly and never completes execution

